# What is the replacement period of gastrolithes in doves?

Tags: ornithology, gastroenterology

[Gastrolithes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastrolith) are common in doves and pigeons. Do they keep ingested stones for ever? If not, how often are they to be replaced?